# Sqlite merge columns in join

Tags: sqlite, join, merge

I got two tables:

**emails**

```
raw_id | email | score

1, email1, 1
1, email2, 2
2, email3, 3
3, email4, 4
```

**merged**

```
raw_id1 | raw_id2

1, 2
```

How can I make a query that will show me one row for each distinct `row_id` with highest `score`, also if two `raw_id` are merged they will be considered as same one.

So for the above data, here is my expected result:

```
select score, email from emails join...
```

- 3, email3
- 4, email4
  -

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your merged table. edit: I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(e1.raw_id, COALESCE(e2.raw_id, -1)),
       MAX(e1.email),
       MAX(MAX(e1.score, COALESCE(e2.score, -1)))
FROM emails e1 LEFT JOIN merged m
    ON e1.raw_id = m.raw_id1
LEFT JOIN emails e2
    ON e2.raw_id = m.raw_id2
GROUP BY MAX(e1.raw_id, COALESCE(e2.raw_id, -1))
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Note that this demo is for MySQL, because Fiddle doesn't offer the option for SQLite.  The only change I had to make to the query was to replace SQLite's scalar `MAX` function with MySQL's `GREATEST` function.

Comment: I just run this, it result in 3 raws, email2, email3, email4

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Reload the page please.  I have made a couple of changes perhaps.

Comment: This is strange, it works in MySql but not in SQLite. I added the explain to your question.

Comment: That dump didn't help the situation.  What output do you get from SQLite, or do you get an error?  `EXPLAIN` is more of a performance thing, rather than yes/no does the query work.

Comment: It does say much, no errors: 3 rows returned in 1ms from: SELECT MAX(e1.raw_id, COALESCE(e2.raw_id, -1)),
       MAX(e1.email),
       MAX(MAX(e1.score, COALESCE(e2.score, -1)))
FROM emails e1 LEFT JOIN merged m
    ON e1.raw_id = m.raw_id1
LEFT JOIN emails e2
    ON e2.raw_id = m.raw_id2
GROUP BY MAX(e1.raw_id, COALESCE(e2.raw_id, -1))

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Please thoroughly check the data in your table.  The extra group could be getting generated though whitespace or something similar.  I don't believe my query should logically be including an extra email.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Maybe you could mention the issue you were having, just in case someone else has a similar problem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(score), email
  FROM emails
       LEFT JOIN
       merged ON emails.raw_id = merged.raw_id1 
 GROUP BY coalesce(raw_id2, raw_id);
```

Comment: Consider clarifiying your answer.

Comment: Clarify how? It's the query he asked for.